# Error on Importing module numpy.math

Tags: python, numpy

when I use

```
from numpy.math import factorial as fact
```

I get : `ImportError: No module named 'numpy.math'`

but

```
import numpy
fact=numpy.math.factorial
```

works.

Why ? Is numpy.math really implemented like other modules ?

Comment: I don't think there's a math module in numpy. I couldn't find any...

Answer (score 3):

numpy seems to import the standard `math` library:

```
In [8]: import numpy

In [9]: import math

In [10]: math is numpy.math
Out[10]: True
```

So it is not the submodule of numpy, just an imported module object. That is why you can not import like this: `from numpy.math import something` .

Comment: my problem is :
 The way to load the functions is not the same. Not the way to use them.

Maybe is it an installation probem ?

Comment: I don't know. It have not enought information to say anything. Perhaps numpy have been changed. In my case: numpy.__version__ ==  '1.13.1', I use with Python 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Arpad Horvath's answer has already shown, that `numpy.math` is not different from the `math` library and therefore won't work on numpy arrays that can't be converted to scalars. But you can use [`scipy.misc.factorial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.factorial.html#scipy.misc.factorial):

```
import scipy.misc
a = np.arange(5)
print(scipy.misc.factorial(a))
#output
#[ 1.  1.  2.  6. 24.]
```

This is deprecated in scipy 1.0.0, though still working. Use [`scipy.special.factorial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.factorial.html#scipy.special.factorial) instead.
Other mathematical functions implemented for arrays are [listed here in `numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html) and [here in `scipy.specials`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html)

Comment: Sorry but it's not my question

Comment: Different libraries. [One working with scalars, the other with arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48226089/8881141) That they have the same name, doesn't mean anything for the mathematical operations under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Don't need numpy, just use

```
from math import factorial as fact
```

Comment: Yes I know, I would like to know why
from numpy.math import factorial -->  doesnt' work

to compare whith
from numpy.random import randint --> works

same syntax, ...