# How to solve an equation which has a solution variable in form of function at both side of equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy

I want to plot a graph of an equation in Python which has a solution variable at both sides in form of some function.
The equation is:

```
i = Ip - Io*(exp((V+i*R1)/(n*Vt)) - 1) - (V +I*R1)/(R2)
```

where `Ip, Io, n, R1, R2, Vt` are some constants.

I want to iterate `V` in the range `(0,10)` and want to get values for `i` using Python and plot a `V-i` graph.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
r = 50
V = np.linspace(0,10,r)

def current():
    current = []
    for t in V:
        i = np.zeros(r)
        Ipv = 3
        Rs = 0.221
        Rsh = 415
        n = 2
        m = 1.5
        T = 302
        Eg = 1.14
        K = 1.3
        Vt = T/11600
        Io = K*(T**m)*exp(-Eg/(n*Vt))
        i = Ipv - Io *(exp((t + Rs*i)/(n*Vt)) - 1) - (t + Rs * i)/Rsh
        current.append(i)
    return np.array(current)

Icurrent = current()
plt.plot(V,Icurrent)
plt.show()
```

I did this but this not working.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What you describe is a task, not a question. Please show, what you have tried so far as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - SO is not a free coding service. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, your problem is that you mix `numpy` arrays with a scalar `math` function. [Don't do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226089/scipy-curve-fit-doesnt-like-math-module) Substitute it with the appropriate `numpy` function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
r = 50
V = np.linspace(0,10,r)
print(V)

def current():
    current = []
    for t in V:
        i = np.zeros(r)
        Ipv = 3
        Rs = 0.221
        Rsh = 415
        n = 2
        m = 1.5
        T = 302
        Eg = 1.14
        K = 1.3
        Vt = T/11600
        Io = K*(T**m)*np.exp(-Eg/(n*Vt))
        i = Ipv - Io *(np.exp((t + Rs*i)/(n*Vt)) - 1) - (t + Rs * i)/Rsh
        current.append(i)
    return np.array(current)

Icurrent = current()
plt.plot(V,Icurrent)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

I would have suggested using [`scipy.fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html#scipy.optimize.fsolve), but seemingly your approach is working.

Comment: You should remove the `from sympy import *` if you are not using any SymPy functions.