# curve_fit a 2D function containing numpy arrays --> shapes (3,3,9) and (3,1) not aligned: 9 (dim 2) != 3 (dim 0)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, scipy

This is my first question here. I hope I provide sufficient information for you guys.

I ran into problems when using `curve_fit` with a function that uses numpy arrays. Using the function with fixed parameters works fine.

The task:

I want to find two vectors. What I know is how the vectors are rotated around each other and the coordinate system and the resulting angle between one vector and the coordinate system y-axis.

The problem:

`my_func` is the function I want to use but it throws an error only when putting it into `curve_fit`.

`my_func2` should be a breakdown of the problem that works. As far as I can see the functions in principal are the same except for `my_func2` having less and less complex formulas.

This is the code I wrote:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

'''The function I want to optimize. 2D-xdata with 6 free parameters.'''
def my_func(X, hx, hy, hz, lx, ly, lz):

    # These are the two independently measured angles (2D-xdata).
    phi, alpha = X

    # y-axis of the coordinate system.
    yaxis = np.array([[0],
                      [1],
                      [0]])

    # First wanted vector h (first three parameters).
    h = np.array([[hx],
                  [hy],
                  [hz]])

    # Second wanted vector l (last three parameters).
    l = np.array([[lx],
                  [ly],
                  [lz]])

    # Projection matrix.
    Pxy = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0]])

    # Needed to generate the rotation matrix around the unknown vector h.
    h_norm = h / np.linalg.norm(h)
    n1, n2, n3 = h_norm[0][0], h_norm[1][0], h_norm[2][0]

    # Rotation matrix for rotation around the vector h by angle alpha.
    R_h = np.array([[n1 ** 2 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) + np.cos(alpha), n1 * n2 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) - n3 * np.sin(alpha), n1 * n3 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) + n2 * np.sin(alpha)],
                    [n1 * n2 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) + n3 * np.sin(alpha), n2 ** 2 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) + np.cos(alpha), n2 * n3 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) - n1 * np.sin(alpha)],
                    [n1 * n3 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) - n2 * np.sin(alpha), n2 * n3 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) + n1 * np.sin(alpha), n3 ** 2 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) + np.cos(alpha)]])

    # Rotate the vector l around the vector h by angle alpha.
    l_rot = np.dot(R_h, l)

    # Rotation matrix for rotation around x-axis by angle phi.
    R_x = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                    [0, np.cos(phi), -np.sin(phi)],
                    [0, np.sin(phi), np.cos(phi)]])

    # Rotate the vector l_rot around the x-axis by angle phi.
    l_final = np.dot(R_x, l_rot)

    # Project the vector l_final into the xy-plane.
    l_final_xy = np.dot(Pxy, l_final)

    # Get the angle between the projected vector l_final_xy and the y-axis.
    angle = np.arccos(np.vdot(l_final_xy, yaxis) / (np.linalg.norm(l_final_xy)))

    # Return angle in degree.
    return angle * 180 / np.pi


'''A simplified version of the function above with less complex formulas.'''
def my_func2(X, a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3):

    # Represents phi and alpha of my_func.
    x1, x2 = X

    # Represents the first wanted vector of my_func.
    va = np.array([[a1],
                   [a2],
                   [a3]])

    # Represents the second wanted vector of my_func.
    vb = np.array([[b1],
                   [b2],
                   [b3]])

    # Represents the rotation matrix of my_func. It depends on the x-data and the parameters.
    M1 = np.array([[x1 * a1, x2 * b1, 0],
                   [0, x1 * a2, x2 * b2],
                   [x2 * b3, 0, x1 * a3]])

    # Some simplified math with the wanted vectors and the generated matrix.
    v_new = np.vdot(np.dot(M1, va), vb)

    return v_new
```

Here comes some testing.

```
# Some x-data: phi and alpha.
xdata = [[0, 0, 0, 30, 30, 30, 60, 60, 60],
         [0, 90, 180, 0, 90, 180, 0, 90, 180]]

# Some y-data.
ydata = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]

# Test if my_func works as expected.
print(my_func([np.pi / 4, np.pi / 4], 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

This line prints `135.0` which is correct. I also tested other values and the result always looks correct.

```
print(curve_fit(my_func2, xdata, ydata)[0])
```

This line prints `[-0.88635298  2.75337506  0.66050304  0.13882423  0.01404608  0.02166652]`. So the fitting of the simplified problem works.

```
print(curve_fit(my_func, xdata, ydata)[0])
```

This line throws the following error:

`l_rot = np.dot(R_h, l)
ValueError: shapes (3,3,9) and (3,1) not aligned: 9 (dim 2) != 3 (dim 0)`

So the final question is: Why do I run into dimensional problems only when using `curve_fit` and how can I circumvent?

Comment: This is not a curve fitting problem. `my_func(xdata, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)` already produces this error. Reorganize your function that it can work with a 2D numpy array and curve fit will work as well.

Comment: `my_func` is not designed to take a list of two lists (`xdata`) as first argument but a list of two numbers like in my example (`[np.pi / 4, np.pi / 4]`). But your answer makes me wonder if I understood `curve_fit` correctly.

Comment: There you have your problem. Curve fit calls the function with your numpy arrays, not consecutively with x, y pairs from these arrays. That's why, each operation within func has to be a numpy function, not a scalar math function: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48226089/8881141

Comment: Ok, now it works. Thank you very much! But one thing I do not yet understand. Why does `my_func2` work? I do not see the basic difference between `my_func` and `my_func2`.

Comment: I don't know because I haven't analyzed the inner workings of your two functions. Maybe somebody else wants to do that. BTW, you are allowed and encouraged to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Mr.T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8881141/mr-t) I noticed that my understanding of curve fit was wrong. I thought it would iterate over the passed x- and y-data and enter each set of values into the function.

In reality curve fit enters the hole x-data, which is a list / array. The function has to be able to handle that list / array itself, as [Mr.T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8881141/mr-t) explained in his second comment.

To solve my problem I just added a for-loop to my function that iterates over the x-data list / array. The return is now a list of values instead of a single value. One value for each x-data set.

I'm not sure if that is the nicest solution but the working program is below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

'''The function I want to optimize. 2D-xdata with 6 free parameters.'''
def my_func(X, hx, hy, hz, lx, ly, lz):

    angles = []

    for index in range(len(X)):

        # These are the two independently measured angles (2D-xdata).
        phi, alpha = X[index]

        # y-axis of the coordinate system.
        yaxis = np.array([[0],
                          [1],
                          [0]])

        # First wanted vector h (first three parameters).
        h = np.array([[hx],
                      [hy],
                      [hz]])

        # Second wanted vector l (last three parameters).
        l = np.array([[lx],
                      [ly],
                      [lz]])

        # Projection matrix.
        Pxy = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                        [0, 1, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0]])

        # Needed to generate the rotation matrix around the unknown vector h.
        h_norm = h / np.linalg.norm(h)
        n1, n2, n3 = h_norm[0][0], h_norm[1][0], h_norm[2][0]

        # Rotation matrix for rotation around the vector h by angle alpha.
        R_h = np.array([[n1 ** 2 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) + np.cos(alpha), n1 * n2 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) - n3 * np.sin(alpha), n1 * n3 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) + n2 * np.sin(alpha)],
                        [n1 * n2 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) + n3 * np.sin(alpha), n2 ** 2 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) + np.cos(alpha), n2 * n3 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) - n1 * np.sin(alpha)],
                        [n1 * n3 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) - n2 * np.sin(alpha), n2 * n3 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) + n1 * np.sin(alpha), n3 ** 2 * (1 - np.cos(alpha)) + np.cos(alpha)]])

        # Rotate the vector l around the vector h by angle alpha.
        l_rot = np.dot(R_h, l)

        # Rotation matrix for rotation around x-axis by angle phi.
        R_x = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                        [0, np.cos(phi), -np.sin(phi)],
                        [0, np.sin(phi), np.cos(phi)]])

        # Rotate the vector l_rot around the x-axis by angle phi.
        l_final = np.dot(R_x, l_rot)

        # Project the vector l_final into the xy-plane.
        l_final_xy = np.dot(Pxy, l_final)

        # Get the angle between the projected vector l_final_xy and the y-axis.
        angle = np.arccos(np.vdot(l_final_xy, yaxis) / (np.linalg.norm(l_final_xy)))

        angles.append(angle * 180 / np.pi)

    # Return angle in degree.
    return angles

# Some x-data: phi and alpha.
xdata = [[0, 0],
         [0, 90],
         [0, 180],
         [30, 0],
         [30, 90],
         [30, 180],
         [60, 0],
         [60, 90],
         [60, 180]]

# Some y-data.
ydata = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]

print(curve_fit(my_func, xdata, ydata)[0])
```