# Fit experimental data and obtain 2 parameters

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a messy expression to some experimental data. The formula has 2 free parameters (in the code denoted by "a" and "b") and I need to find the values for a and b. I tried using the scipy module but I keep getting an error when compiling the *curve_fit* procedure. I tried to find something regarding the error but I couldn't find anything that solved the issue.

Screenshot with the error:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2suUq.png)

Please keep in mind that my experience with python is not that great (basically I just started to learn it for this fitting procedure). Segment of the code is here if it would make it easier:

```
def fun1(x,a,b):
    result=tsd1(x,17,6.5,a,b)
    return result
params, extras = curve_fit(fun1,mydata.spin,mydata.energy)
print(params)
```

*tsd1* is another function which depends on some parameter (the full expression for the tsd1 function can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/9kVgxuHn) ) and *mydata* are 2 arrays with the spin and energy, represented by the first and second column in the data file. Full input data [here](https://pastebin.com/wLx8knYG)

I would like to know what is wrong with my fitting procedure and how I can solve this issue.

Comment: As you can see, the error message does not fit on the screenshot. That's why we always ask people to provide code and error messages as `formatted text`. Please post the full traceback.

Comment: first column is the spin and second column is the energy.

Comment: It is still not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). tsd1 is missing and you shouldn't post any text on SO as a picture. If I had to guess - you didn't use numpy functions in tsd1. But who knows without having seen tsd1.

Comment: Ah, as expected. You use math functions sqrt, sin, cos on arrays. [Doesn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226089/scipy-curve-fit-doesnt-like-math-module) Still: All relevant code should be posted here on SO. If the link breaks this question would be useless for future visitors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scipy curve\_fit doesn't like math module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226089/scipy-curve-fit-doesnt-like-math-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you experience is that you use the functions of the `math` module (they work on scalars) instead of the `numpy` functions that are designed to work on arrays. A simplified version of your problem (I am too lazy to go through all the functions you declared) would be:

```
from math import cos
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd

#works perfectly fine with the numpy arrays from the pandas data frame
def fun1(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.cos(b * x / 1000 + c) + d

#this version doesn't work because math works only on scalars
#def fun1(x, a, b, c, d):
#    return a * cos(b * x / 1000 + c) + d

#read data from file you provided
mydata = pd.read_csv("test.txt", names = ["spin", "energy"])

#curve fit
params, extras = curve_fit(fun1,mydata.spin,mydata.energy)
print(params)

#generation of the fitting curve
x_fit = np.linspace(np.min(mydata.spin), np.max(mydata.spin), 1000)
y_fit = fun1(x_fit, *params)

#plotting of raw data and fit function
plt.plot(mydata.spin, mydata.energy, "ro", label = "data")
plt.plot(x_fit, y_fit, "b", label = "fit")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

So, the solution is to find all math functions in your script like `sin`, `cos`, `sqrt` and substitute them with their numpy equivalents. Luckily, they are usually simply `np.sin` etc.