# Problems using scipy.odr with math.erf()

Tags: python, python-3.x, one-definition-rule

I have a problem using the orthogonal distance regression with a function using the error function `math.erf()`. To be more clear it seems I have a problem with the variables which should be fit.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import odr
import math

def CDF(x,a,b,c):
   #definition of errorfunction to fit data
   return c/2*(1+math.erf((x-a)/(b*math.sqrt(2))))

#to make things a little shorter I excluded the parts in which the data is 
read and prepared

guess=Ergebnis_popt[1] #using found values for a,b,c from curve_fit without 
errors
guess_a=guess[0]
guess_b=guess[1]
guess_c=guess[2]
xerr=Verschiebung_fit[2] #determination of x_erros, the values for the y 
errors are included in the prepared data
xerr=xerr/xerr
xerr=xerr/200
#building the model for the odr fit, as the erf function seems to only 
handle single values I use np.vectorize
cfd = odr.Model(np.vectorize(CDF,excluded=['a','b','c']),extra_args= 
['a','b','c'])  
#Definition of the Data with ererrors for the fit
mydata =odr.RealData(Verschiebung_fit[2],y=y_values_fit[2],sx=xerr,sy=y_values_fit[4])
#basis for the odr fit
odr=odr.ODR(mydata,cfd, beta0 = [guess_a,guess_b,guess_c] )
myoutput = odr.run()
myoutput.pprint()
```

All this results in a Error:

> File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2785, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
>       outputs = func(*inputs)
>   File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2750, in func
>       return self.pyfunc(*the_args, **kwargs)
>   TypeError: CDF() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

I am a novice using python. I guess there is a problem with communicating the variables which should be fitted, but I can not figure out where this problem occurs.

Comment: It is not the reason for your error message and I have never worked with ODR and ERF, but I guess you can't use math functions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48226089/8881141