# scipy.integrate error:only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, typeerror

I am trying to calculate probabilities from Gaussian Distribution by varying the standard deviation(std).
I am expecting by using the Gaussian Quadrature with 21 points, integrating over a range from -1 to +1 with mean = 0 and setting std= 1 and std =2 will yield p = 0.68 and p = 0.95 respectively (picture attached).

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import math as m

#mean=0
#varying the sigma
def f(sigma,x):
    return m.exp(-1*(x**2)/(2*sigma**2))/(sigma*m.sqrt(2*m.pi))

def prob_at_nsigma(sigma):
    value = 0.
    
    ans,anserr =integrate.quadrature(f,-1,1,args=(sigma ,),maxiter=21)
    value = ans
    return value

print(prob_at_nsigma(1))
```

And I get the following errors which I don't see why the "divide by zero" and "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" arise:

```
runfile('C:/pythonExe/ntu_cp/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/pythonExe/ntu_cp')
C:\pythonExe\ntu_cp\untitled0.py:14: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  return m.exp(-1*(x**2)/(2*sigma**2))/(sigma*m.sqrt(2*m.pi))
C:\pythonExe\ntu_cp\untitled0.py:14: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  return m.exp(-1*(x**2)/(2*sigma**2))/(sigma*m.sqrt(2*m.pi))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\pythonExe\ntu_cp\untitled0.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(prob_at_nsigma(1))

  File "C:\pythonExe\ntu_cp\untitled0.py", line 19, in prob_at_nsigma
    ans,anserr =integrate.quadrature(f,-1,1,args=(sigma ,),maxiter=21)

  File "C:\Users\cztee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadrature.py", line 238, in quadrature
    newval = fixed_quad(vfunc, a, b, (), n)[0]

  File "C:\Users\cztee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadrature.py", line 119, in fixed_quad
    return (b-a)/2.0 * np.sum(w*func(y, *args), axis=-1), None

  File "C:\Users\cztee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadrature.py", line 149, in vfunc
    return func(x, *args)

  File "C:\pythonExe\ntu_cp\untitled0.py", line 14, in f
    return m.exp(-1*(x**2)/(2*sigma**2))/(sigma*m.sqrt(2*m.pi))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

[Gaussian distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fuWD.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scipy curve\_fit doesn't like math module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226089/scipy-curve-fit-doesnt-like-math-module) In summary: Substitute the math functions with the corresponding numpy functions.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.T! I didn't know that scipy assumes 1D- array input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems in your code:

- As mentioned, you should use `numpy` instead of `math` module.
- Your `f` function's argument order is wrong. Scipy assumes that the first variable is `x` followed by other parameters. So it should be `f(x, sigma)`, not `f(sigma, x)`.

Solution:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

def f(x, sigma):
    return np.exp(-1*(x**2)/(2*sigma**2))/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))

def prob_at_nsigma(sigma):
    value = 0.
    ans, anserr = integrate.quadrature(f, -1, 1, args=(sigma,), maxiter=21)
    return ans

print(prob_at_nsigma(1))
# 0.6826894922280757
```