# performing a math function for array

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to programming so, I might sound naive.
I have a set of arrays

`matrix([[0.23316744, 0.62686578, 0.23497639, 0.41566779, 0.18428155]]), matrix([[0.26199825, 0.7148431 , 0.2296318 , 0.36555626, 0.18962302]]),............. etc.`

I would like to perform the math.arctan function on each element and bring it back to the same format to perform further operations.

I cannot perform the math.arctan on it directly since it gives the error

`TypeError: must be real number, not list`

so I tried using the np.asscalar to separate each term but it does not work and gives the error

`TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Any help in this would be really helpful.

Comment: You cannot use [math functions with numpy arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48226089/8881141) But you can use `np.arctan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it gives you the error

```
TypeError: must be real number, not list
```

because the function Math.arctan Expect a number not a List ,
a simple solution is to loop into your list and for each element L[i][j] do L[i][j] = Math.arctan(L[i][j])

in this code, I suppose you have a list of list and each child liste contain numbers

```
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    for j in range(0,len(l[i])):
        L[i][j] = Math.arctan(L[i][j])
```