# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when try to plot a 2D signal

Tags: python

I try to plot a 2D-signal, with the expression:

[image]

Below is my function for the equation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

u = np.linspace(-(np.pi), np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(-(np.pi), np.pi, 100)

def h(u, v):
    return (0.01/(1-0.9*cmath.exp(-complex(imag=u))-0.9*cmath.exp(-complex(imag=v))+0.81*(cmath.exp(-complex(imag=u+v)))))

U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)
H = h(U, V)
fig = plt.figure()


The error raised:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-4bc2c2bf8d66> in <module>()  
----> 2 H = h(U, V)

<ipython-input-37-b322d7cf29d0> in h(u, v)
      1 def h(u, v):
----> 2     return (0.01/(1-0.9*np.exp(-complex(imag=u))-0.9*np.exp(-complex(imag=v))+0.81*(np.exp(-complex(imag=u+v)))))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: [Don't mix math with numpy.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226089/scipy-curve-fit-doesnt-like-math-module)

Comment: thx, i wil try again!

Comment: Hi , i only used numpy not for all variables, but error still exists, any suggestion?

Comment: Please update your question with a reproducible example. I suggest reading [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello Mr.T, i edited my question, thank you for ur advice.

Comment: What applies to `math`, also applies to `cmath`. Try `print(cmath.exp(-complex(imag=u)))` with `u=2`, `u=np.asarray([2])`, and `u=np.asarray([2, 3])`.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem.You can try to replace `math.exp` with `np.exp`.