# Input from txt file and simple plot using function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

So I have data in txt file like this:

| Frequency | faze |
| --- | --- |
| 100.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 125.892541 | 0.000000 |
| 158.489319 | 0.000000 |
| 199.526231 | -1.440000 |
| 251.188643 | 0.000000 |
| 316.227766 | -2.278481 |

Now I want to create plot in which the x-axis is `frequency` and the y-axis is `faze`. Also, I would like to use curve_fit function which is implemented like this:

```
def f(x, a, b):
    return a * np.arctan(b * x)
```

Right now my code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np
import scipy.optimize
import math

with open('dane.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    freq = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
    enter = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
    exit = [float(line.split()[2]) for line in lines]
    faze = [float(line.split()[3]) for line in lines]


def f(x, a, b):
    return a * np.arctan(b * x)

p1, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, freq, faze)
print('params = {}'.format(p1))
print('errors = {}'.format(np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel('Frequency')
ax.set_ylabel('Faze')
ax.set_title('Simple graph')
ax.grid()
ax.plot(freq, f(freq, *p1), label='fit')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

But here I have a problem. I get this error:
*TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars*
When I try to change data to int I get error like this:
*ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100.000000'*
Then I changed the input to floats, but after that I got error like this:
*TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'*
Right now I'm stuck on this part.

Comment: You should convert the strings to numeric, e.g. `float(line.split()[0])`

Comment: @JohanC I tried this one. Then again I get error like this: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: @JohanC No. I just added them for clarity. It's just 2 columns separated by spaces.

Comment: Don't mix [numpy arrays with math functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48226089/8881141).

Comment: @Mr.T I changed the math.atan for np.arctan and added p0 to my curve_fit. Now i get this error: TypeError: f() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given.

Comment: Did you try to make sure `freq` etc are numpy arrays of numbers? As in `freq = np.array([float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines])`?

Comment: I don't think that p0 is really needed. I changed from math.atan to np.arctan. I think that the only problem now is the error that I get from this change: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'

Comment: @JohanC Yeah. The data input is alright.

Comment: You should edit your question to the current code, post the full traceback of the error message, and provide sample data as lists in your question, if the import is not your problem here. As for `p0` - you will find out soon that curve_fit is very much dependent on good initial guesses but this is not the source of your problem at the moment.

Comment: @Mr.T You're right. I edited the question to what I have now.

Comment: Scipy uses internally numpy arrays - it converts your lists to these arrays. You have to do this manually if you want to plot it: `ax.plot(freq, f(np.asarray(freq), *p1), label='fit')`. In general, it is better to convert lists to numpy arrays when using scipy.curve_fit.

Comment: Ok. I changed it to numpy array and It works. Thank you very much !