# How build two graphs in one figure, module Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How to build two graphs in one figure from the equations below

1. y = (x+2)^2
2. y = sin(x/2)^2

There is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import sin

y = lambda x: sin(x / 2) ** 2
y1 = lambda x: (x + 2) ** 2

fig = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)

plt.plot(x, y(x))
plt.plot(x, y1(x))

plt.show()
```

Comment: You cannot use `math` functions with numpy arrays. Use `np.sin()` instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226089/scipy-curve-fit-doesnt-like-math-module) for more information on this problem.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: FYI, your question lacked detail, namely what your problem was. Obviously, you get an error message - so you should have specified the error message in the question. As you can see, people interpreted your question differently ("Why do I get an error message?", "How do I plot two functions in one graph?", and "How do I plot functions into subplots?"). All three interpretations are valid, so you have to make sure to specify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`supplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to make 2 Axes in your Figure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)

ax1.plot(x, np.sin(x / 2) ** 2)
ax2.plot(x, (x + 2) ** 2)
```

[image]