# Plotting log function with two variables

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, logarithm

I'm looking to plot some function but the logarithm function keeps giving me this error:

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

This is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import math
%matplotlib notebook

def f10(x,y):
    return x*math.log(y,2) + y*math.log(x,2)

x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)
y = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)
#x = np.arange(-3.2, 3.2, 0.2)
#y = np.arange(-3.2, 3.2, 0.2)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f10(X,Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,cmap='jet', edgecolor = 'none')
ax.set_title("Surface", fontsize = 13)
ax.set_xlabel('x', fontsize = 11)
ax.set_ylabel('y', fontsize = 11)
ax.set_zlabel('Z', fontsize = 11)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')


func = np.vectorize(f10)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
p=ax.contour(X, Y, func(X,Y))

fig.colorbar(surf)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scipy curve\_fit doesn't like math module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226089/scipy-curve-fit-doesnt-like-math-module) TLDR: Don't mix numpy arrays with math module functions, use the numpy functions instead.

Comment: To be specific: replace `math.log` with `np.log`.