# Generating 2D synthetic data: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python

How can I fix this error?

```
X1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 100);
X2 = np.linspace(0,1,100);
print(X1);
print(X2);
Y = math.sin((X1) + 5*(X2)) + np.random.normal(0,0.1,len(X1))
```

Comment: For a more detailed explanation, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48226089/8881141

Answer (score 0):

`math.sin` is not made to work with NumPy arrays. Use [`np.sin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html) instead

```py
Y = np.sin((X1) + 5*(X2)) + np.random.normal(0,0.1,len(X1))
```