# Plotting Using Trapezodial Rule

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

So I am trying to plot f = cos(x) using the trapezoidal rule but I keep getting an error saying:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I am not sure how the function is spitting out an array and not values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as math



f = lambda x : math.cosh(4*x)
a = 0
b = 5
N = 8

# x and y values for the trapezoid rule
x = np.linspace(a,b,N+1)
y = f(x)

# X and Y values for plotting y=f(x)
X = np.linspace(a,b,100)
Y = f(X)
plt.plot(X,Y)

for i in range(N):
    xs = [x[i],x[i],x[i+1],x[i+1]]
    ys = [0,f(x[i]),f(x[i+1]),0]
    plt.fill(xs,ys,'b',edgecolor='b',alpha=0.2)

plt.title('Trapezoid Rule, N = {}'.format(N))
plt.show()
```

Comment: [Don't use math with numpy arrays.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226089/scipy-curve-fit-doesnt-like-math-module)

Answer (score 0):

No need to mix frameworks, use:

```
f = lambda x : np.cosh(4*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as math



f = lambda x : math.cosh(4*x)
a = 0
b = 5
N = 8

# x and y values for the trapezoid rule
x = np.linspace(a,b,N+1)
y = [f(i) for i in x]  # this is a change

# X and Y values for plotting y=f(x)
X = np.linspace(a,b,100)
Y = [f(j) for j in X]  #this is a change
plt.plot(X,Y)
```

[image]

```
for i in range(N):
    xs = [x[i],x[i],x[i+1],x[i+1]]
    ys = [0,f(x[i]),f(x[i+1]),0]
    plt.fill(xs,ys,'b',edgecolor='b',alpha=0.2)

plt.title('Trapezoid Rule, N = {}'.format(N))
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have commented the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, I dont really like the plt.fill option my professor gave. How can I change this so the Trapezoidal function is plotted like a line? Hopefully that makes sense.