# Type error in matplotlib using math module

Tags: python, matplotlib, typeerror

My c_l variable creates a graph, but my U variable returns "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars". Any tips to resolve this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

alpha = np.linspace(10,90,200)
gamma = 90
phi = 45
omega = alpha - phi
m = 0.14
g = 9.81
rho = 1.225 # air density
A = 0.45

# my polynomial
c_l = ((-3.75*10**(-11))*alpha**6) + ((6.234*10**(-9))*alpha**5) + ((4.663*10**(-8))*alpha**4) + ((-5.419*10**(-5))*alpha**3) + ((2.474*10**(-3))*alpha**2) + ((-7.349*10**(-3))*alpha) + (1.9*10**(-1))
c_d = ((-6.019*10**(-11))*alpha**6) + ((1.937*10**(-8))*alpha**5) + ((-2.23*10**(-6))*alpha**4) + ((1.072*10**(-4))*alpha**3) + ((-1.951*10**(-3))*alpha**2) + ((2.968*10**(-2))*alpha) + (-1.389*10**(-1))

plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(alpha, c_l, label = 'lift', color = '#0056c7')
plt.plot(alpha, c_d, label = 'drag', color = '#d62b00')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('alpha')
plt.ylabel('coefficients')
plt.title('Coefficient of lift polynomial')
plt.show()

# V = vertical speed
U = math.sqrt((2*m*g)/(rho*A*((c_d*math.cos(omega))+(c_l*math.sin(omega)))))
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(alpha, U)
plt.show()
```

Comment: [Don't mix scalar (math) and array (numpy) functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226089/scipy-curve-fit-doesnt-like-math-module). Use instead the corresponding numpy functions.

Answer (score 0):

Using np instead of math for sqrt, cos and sin removes the error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

alpha = np.linspace(10,90,200)
gamma = 90
phi = 45
omega = alpha - phi
m = 0.14
g = 9.81
rho = 1.225 # air density
A = 0.45

# my polynomial
c_l = ((-3.75*10**(-11))*alpha**6) + ((6.234*10**(-9))*alpha**5) + ((4.663*10**(-8))*alpha**4) + ((-5.419*10**(-5))*alpha**3) + ((2.474*10**(-3))*alpha**2) + ((-7.349*10**(-3))*alpha) + (1.9*10**(-1))
c_d = ((-6.019*10**(-11))*alpha**6) + ((1.937*10**(-8))*alpha**5) + ((-2.23*10**(-6))*alpha**4) + ((1.072*10**(-4))*alpha**3) + ((-1.951*10**(-3))*alpha**2) + ((2.968*10**(-2))*alpha) + (-1.389*10**(-1))

plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(alpha, c_l, label = 'lift', color = '#0056c7')
plt.plot(alpha, c_d, label = 'drag', color = '#d62b00')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('alpha')
plt.ylabel('coefficients')
plt.title('Coefficient of lift polynomial')
plt.show()
# V = vertical speed
U = np.sqrt((2*m*g)/(rho*A*((c_d*np.cos(omega))+(c_l*np.sin(omega)))))
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(alpha, U)
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]